# Subdirectoriy return incorrect content Nginx autoindex with dynamic path

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I want to use autoindex to expose some files on the server. For convenience, I want to use short_id in the url, but use full_id on the file system.

When I try to access subdirectories or download files, I always get the content of the root directory, and it does not return the content I need correctly

For example: visiting `examlple.com/12345` and `example.com/12345/subdirectory` got the same result

I tried the following configuration.

```
map $room_id $path_name {
    "12345" "12345-ABCD";
    "6789" "disable";
    default "null";
}

server
{
    root /disk1/web/root/path;

    location ~^/(.*?)/(.*) {
        set $room_id $1;
        set $url /$2;

        if ( $path_name = "null" ){
            return 404;
        }

        if ( $path_name = "disable" ){
            return 403;
        }

        alias /disk2/path/to/$path_name/;
        autoindex on;

        #Send the data in JSON
        autoindex_format json;
        addition_types application/json;

        #Calling from SERVERNAME/autoindex/*
        add_before_body /autoindex/header.html;
        add_after_body /autoindex/footer.html;

        #Need to tell that we are sending HTML
        add_header Content-Type text/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: You capture `$url` from the requested URL and never use it. Perhaps you should use `alias /disk2/path/to/$path_name$url;` - BTW, it may be better to choose a different name than `$url` as there is already a very similar looking internally defined variable called `$uri`.

Comment: By using `/path/to/$path_name$url;` problem solved! !
I originally wanted to change the behavior of autoindex through the $url variable, so I had this stupid operation. ( ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `/path/to/$path_name$2;` problem solved! ! Thanks Richard Smith!!!

> You capture $url from the requested URL and never use it. Perhaps you should use alias /disk2/path/to/$path_name$url; - BTW, it may be better to choose a different name than $url as there is already a very similar looking internally defined variable called $uri. –
> Richard Smith

> First time using this platform, didn't find how to set commit as the correct answer, so copied it down, if there is anything wrong, please let me know